# Magento Controller to Handle Any Action

Tags: magento

I've created a custom magento module that is loaded by hitting mysite.com/browse.

I need to be able to load the index regardless of anything after the /browse. For example:

```
mysite.com/browse/cat 
mysite.com/browse/cat/car/jump
mysite.com/browse/bob
- would all load the index of browse
```

I've tried using an htaccess file to do a rewrite but the routing of Magento is causing issues there...  Is there a way that I can tell my module to load the index if an action isn't found instead of rendering a 404?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

in your module controller override method `hasAction`

```
 public function hasAction($action)
 {
     if(!method_exists($this, $this->getActionMethodName($action))) {
         $this->_forward('*/*/index');
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but magento was still responding with a 404 for some reason.

Comment: I was testing that code before post, and it worked on magento 1.8 so dont know what else i can advise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [article](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml) I ended up defining a rewrite in the modules config.xml that took everything after the browse and pass it onto the index of the controller.

```
<rewrite>
    <browse_index_index>
        <from><![CDATA[/browse\/(.*)/]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[browse/index/index/$1/]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </browse_index_index>
</rewrite>
```